# Checking Centered Knights

Tags: chess

[image]

The standard chess end game position above most probably results in a draw. On his turn White player placed the bishop to f5  and say "checks" (board pieces as shown). How can the Black player move his knights legally from this current position?

Comment: It's a double check. You **must** move the king.

Comment: Black player should not lost

Comment: So the solution is a sequence of moves?

Comment: It's only a draw because it will take longer than 50 moves to mate.  Without that restriction, white wins with best play on both sides.

Comment: @Jakob-No, but touch move rule applied . look carefully

Comment: This configuration shouldn't be possible (even with the touch move rule); because black is already in check before Bf5 (thanks to the rook on b3).

Comment: It is double discovery check

Comment: @Tacoタコス Bishop could've been on d3 before move to f5

Comment: @TCooper good eye!

Comment: @Tacoタコス Still no idea how to move a knight though! I'm assuming this has to be some wordplay/ off-the-wall trick. TSLF - are there any other tags that could be added as a clue?

Comment: @Taco-this is common OTB playing..clue: 'think inside the box' puzzle

Comment: he could offer a draw and if accepted, move both knights back into the box :)

Comment: On the right track. But moving the knights after an agreed draw or adjournment is not even illegal or legal. and no longer the current position..Maybe but not the intended solution.

Comment: ..clues in picture

Comment: FYI, K+R+B usually wins against K+N+N and [endgame databases](https://www.shredderchess.com/online/endgame-database.html) confirm this is no exception: Black loses in 185 moves. (Well, ignoring the 50-move-rule of course...) https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SAX4.png

Comment: Looks like since k+n draws  with K+R.. white should avoid any exchange. Try at depth 20 Chess.com analysis  white  can win since no restriction in moves. But human win is not likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second Attempt

Based on OPs comments I now believe

> Black says "J'adoube", which means "I adjust", and centers both his knights which are slightly off center.  He then proceeds to move his King

Note

> you can/should only adjust on your turn, so it is appropriate for black to do so.  Also, technically he wouldn't need to say anything, because although it's touch-move, the knights have no legal move so black would not be forced to move either of them

First Answer

The only thing I can think that of that would allow a knight to move is

> White made an illegal move

So

> Black points it out and White must make a legal move with the bishop since he touched it.  The bishop must have been between the rook and king, but if it were on c3 or e3, Bxd4 wins. d3 would mean it was a legal move.  So it was on f3 or g3 and black can draw after the bishop moves.  However if it were on f3, Bg4+ forces the king, not a knight to move.  So the bishop was on g3.  After something like Bxe5, Nxb3+ draws.

Comment: Boring, but seems right... no standard next move is possible. +1

Comment: White lost by illegal move.

Comment: @TSLF Iiii don't understand what you mean.  Making an illegal move doesn't lose a game according to the official rules of chess

Comment: After white retracts the illegal move and makes another, black can move a knight from another position, not the current one, as required.

Comment: if you make an illegal move in chess, you will either lose the game immediately or after the arbiters have decided the game by carefully reviewing the game. Most of the time, if an illegal move has occurred during a game, the arbiter may decide to restart the game, or by default, your opponent wins.

Comment: @TSLF in blitz/speed chess, maybe.  But the USCF rule (FIDE is similar) is: If a player completes an illegal move by pressing the clock, in addition to the usual obligation to make a legal move with the touched piece if possible, the standard penalty specified in rule 1C2a applies (i.e. two minutes added to the opponent’s clock)

Comment: Yes but still standard chess

Comment: @SteveV-Black player must ask J'adoube during blitz or rapid game

Answer (score 2):

There is only one situation where it is legal for the black player to move the knights from this position, because

> moving "knights" implies moving several pieces at once.

That can only happen while castling, or according to

> [Fide](https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/LawsOfChess.pdf) [laws](https://xkcd.com/169/) [of chess](https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/LawsOfChess.pdf):
>  *7.5 If during a game it is found that pieces have been displaced from their squares, the position before the irregularity shall be re-instated. If the position immediately before the irregularity cannot be determined, the game shall continue from the last identifiable position prior to the irregularity.*

This is the only possibility, since

> if white disturbed the position on his previous move, white must fix it, not black.

Comment: I think your comment to my answer also applies here, if you reset a knight, black isn't moving from this position

Comment: say there's a term for this

Comment: @TSLF you mean J'adoube?